# Navbar - tab positioning

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

How can i make it so that "Login" is positioned on the far right hand side of the screen? I would also like to make a separate header file. However, as you can see i use id="open" in order to have the open tab styled differently then that would be amazing. I would like to do it without JavaScript but from research i think that's my only option.

```
<div> 
    <div class="w3-bar tablink">
        <a class="tablink w3-bar-item w3-button" style="text-decoration:none" id="open" href="index.php">Home</a>
        <a class="tablink w3-bar-item w3-button" style="text-decoration:none" href='matchday.php'>Matchday</a>
        <a class="tablink w3-bar-item w3-button" style="text-decoration:none" href='news.php'>News Page</a>
        <a class="tablink w3-bar-item w3-button" style="text-decoration:none" href='stats.php'>Stats</a>
        <a class="tablink w3-bar-item w3-button" style="text-decoration:none" href='gallery.php'>Gallery</a>
        <a class="tablink w3-bar-item w3-button" style="text-decoration:none" href='forum.php'>Forum</a>
        <a class="tablink w3-bar-item w3-button" style="text-decoration:none" href='more.php'>More...</a>
        <a class="tablink w3-bar-item w3-button" style="text-decoration:none" href='login.php'>Login</a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use flexbox on the wrapping div and use `margin-left:auto` on the last link

```css
.tablink {
  display: flex;
}

.tablink a:last-child {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="w3-bar tablink">
  <a class="tablink w3-bar-item w3-button" style="text-decoration:none" id="open" href="index.php">Home</a>
  <a class="tablink w3-bar-item w3-button" style="text-decoration:none" href='matchday.php'>Matchday</a>
  <a class="tablink w3-bar-item w3-button" style="text-decoration:none" href='news.php'>News Page</a>
  <a class="tablink w3-bar-item w3-button" style="text-decoration:none" href='stats.php'>Stats</a>
  <a class="tablink w3-bar-item w3-button" style="text-decoration:none" href='gallery.php'>Gallery</a>
  <a class="tablink w3-bar-item w3-button" style="text-decoration:none" href='forum.php'>Forum</a>
  <a class="tablink w3-bar-item w3-button" style="text-decoration:none" href='more.php'>More...</a>
  <a class="tablink w3-bar-item w3-button" style="text-decoration:none" href='login.php'>Login</a></div>
```

Comment: Hi thank you for that! Worked a treat. Any idea on how i could indent it to be away from the margin?

Answer (score 0):

add this:

```
<div class="w3-bar tablink" style="float:right">
```

Comment: This solution will make the tabs to appear in reverse order from the original html markup.

Comment: Flexbox is a more recent way of doing this and handles things way better.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div> 
    <div class="w3-bar tablink">
        <a class="tablink w3-bar-item w3-button" style="text-decoration:none" id="open" href="index.php">Home</a>
        <a class="tablink w3-bar-item w3-button" style="text-decoration:none" href='matchday.php'>Matchday</a>
        <a class="tablink w3-bar-item w3-button" style="text-decoration:none" href='news.php'>News Page</a>
        <a class="tablink w3-bar-item w3-button" style="text-decoration:none" href='stats.php'>Stats</a>
        <a class="tablink w3-bar-item w3-button" style="text-decoration:none" href='gallery.php'>Gallery</a>
        <a class="tablink w3-bar-item w3-button" style="text-decoration:none" href='forum.php'>Forum</a>
        <a class="tablink w3-bar-item w3-button" style="text-decoration:none" href='more.php'>More...</a>
        <a class="tablink w3-bar-item w3-button" style="text-decoration:none; float:right" href='login.php'>Login</a></div>
</div>
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/gugui3z24/wnbbzhwL/1/